# How to store the binary files from android to mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, binary, blob

I want to store the sent files from android to mysql but the blob field is null.

this is my code in php

```
<?php

    $target_path  = "./";
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {

    $fileName = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['size']; // file size
    $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']);
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    @mysql_select_db('client') or die("<b>Unable to specified database</b>");


    $query = "INSERT INTO files            (Username,f_id,PathFilename,DateSent,File,Filesize)
    VALUES ('d',' ','$fileName',' ',' $data','$fileSize')";
    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
    }
    else
    {
   echo  "Weak here";
    }

?>
```

this is my code in android

```
        Log.e(Tag, "Inside second Method");

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                exsistingFileName));

        // open a URL connection to the Servlet

        URL url = new URL(urlString);


        // Open a HTTP connection to the URL

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        // Allow Outputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        // Don't use a cached copy.
        conn.setUseCaches(false);

        // Use a post method.
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: post-data; name=uploadedfile;filename="
                        + exsistingFileName + "" + lineEnd); // ito ung file

        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        Log.e(Tag, "Headers are written");

        // create a buffer of maximum size

        int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        int maxBufferSize = 1000;
        // int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesAvailable];

        // read file and write it into form...

        int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bytesAvailable = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);
        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...

        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // close streams
        Log.e(Tag, "File is written");
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Log.e(Tag, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    dialog.dismiss();
    System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn
                .getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.e("Dialoge Box", "Message: " + line);
        }
        rd.close();

    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
    }
}
```

The uploaded file from android was successfully uploaded and the name and size of the file was inserted to the database
But the blob field which is the File(field) shows 0B.. please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$data = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']));
```

Maybe this will help